# How many countries have sent personnel to the ISS?

Tags: iss, astronauts

How many countries have sent astronauts or other trained personnel to the International Space Station?

Answer (score 16):

Wikipedia has a [list of International Space Station crew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_International_Space_Station_crew) where you can also find relevant statistics. As of January 2017, 10 nations have sent *crew* to the ISS: United States, Russia, Japan, Italy, Canada, Germany, France, Belgium, Netherlands and the United Kingdom.

However, more people/nations have *visited* the ISS: [List of International Space Station visitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_International_Space_Station_visitors). This adds another 8 nations to the list: Sweden, Brazil, Denmark, Kazakhstan, Malaysia, South Africa, South Korea and Spain.

So in total, people from 18 nations have been to the ISS as of January 2017.

Comment: That's weird, because I distinctly remember Christer Fugelsang (STS-116 and STS-128) who is Swedish, and worked on construction of the ISS. I don't know why he is not listed on the wikipedia page, perhaps he was registered as a shuttle crew member and never an ISS member, that said however, he was technically sent to the ISS, which is what the OP is asking. I suggest you expand your answer to include more missions than just what is on that wikipedia page.

Comment: @Innovine Thanks, I've expanded the answer. Found another list.